# How do I find which points in a rolling window linear regression (using rollapply) are being used?

Tags: r, linear-regression, zoo, rollapply

I am using the rollapply function to get the slope estimates of fluorescence across days over a a rolling window of 3 days (to find the maximal slope).

This is the code I am using:
the cumulative_dataframe snippet is here: [Cumulative_dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EXHw.png)

```
ls <- cumulative_df %>%
group_by(id) %>%
filter(n() >= 3) %>%
filter(id!="Blank") %>%
group_split()
z_out <- data.frame(intercept = NA, mu = NA, rsqr = NA, id = NA)
k <- moving_window_point_number
for (i in seq_along(ls)) {
z <- ls[[i]] %>% select(day, lRFU)
tmp_df1 <- rollapply(z, width = k,
                   function(x) coef(lm(lRFU ~ day, data = as.data.frame(x))),
                   by.column = FALSE, align = "right")
tmp_df2 <- rollapply(z, width = k,
                   function(x) summary(lm(lRFU ~ day, data = as.data.frame(x)))$r.squared,
                   by.column = FALSE, align = "right")
tmps <- data.frame(intercept = tmp_df1[,1], mu = tmp_df1[,2], rsqr = tmp_df2) %>% arrange(-mu)
z_out[i,1:3] <- as.numeric(c(tmps[1,1], tmps[1,2], tmps[1,3]))
z_out[i,4] <- as.character(unique(ls[[i]]$id))

tmp_df1 <- NULL
tmp_df2 <- NULL
tmps <- NULL
z <- NULL
}
 write_xlsx(z_out,
 paste0(output_dir, cond_new, "gr_estimates_k", k, ".xlsx"))
```

I'm not sure how to do even begin to do this.

Comment: Please read the info at the top of the [tag:r] tag page on asking questions and in particular provide the inputs in text form and provide complete inputs including moving_window_point_number and those `library` statements needed to run the code so others can easily run it.  You likely need `fill=NA` and `coredata = FALSE` argument` to `rollapply`.  `rollapplyr` with r on the end can be used to avoid `align = "right"`.  Also `day` is all zero in the image so the slope will be NA.

Comment: Also it looks like each group has only one row.